# Setting up polipo proxy behind nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, transparent-proxy

I need to put polipo transparent proxy behind nginx reverse proxy. I need this to route trafic to specific polipo instances based on specific domains. For example, proxy-1.domain.com should be routed by nginx (proxy_pass) to first polipo instance and proxy-2.domain.com to second.

**nginx**:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     proxy-1.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://polipo-1:8123;
    }
 }
```

**But when I trying to request nginx I get polipo welcome page:**

> Welcome to
>   Polipo
>
> ## Welcome to Polipo
>
> The Polipo manual.
>
> The configuration interface.

Any help appreciated. Maybe someone can guide me to a better solution.

Comment: It appears to be working just fine. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to add basic authentication to a proxy, as well as domain based routing (proxy1.domain.com to polipo-1, proxy2.domain.com to polipo-2, etc)